# Gini indices of wealth for each country

Tags: data-request, geospatial

Where can I find a colored World Map (A choropleth map) with the various Gini indices of wealth for each country (not Gini indices of income)?

I have searched the Internet and could only find the latter. The Gini index varies between zero and one to show economic disparities between citizens.

Answer (score 2):

My mapping tool (Tableau) may not pick up all the countries with its auto-mapping from country name, but here is a map based on the data available at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_distribution_of_wealth#List).

[image]

And a quick paste of the data to make a better map:

```
Country,Wealth Gini
Albania,0.642
Algeria,0.67
Antigua and Barbuda,0.747
Argentina,0.74
Armenia,0.684
Australia,0.622
Austria,0.646
Azerbaijan,0.678
Bangladesh,0.66
Barbados,0.706
Belarus,0.628
Belgium,0.662
Belize,0.763
Benin,0.713
Bolivia,0.762
Botswana,0.751
Brazil,0.62
Bulgaria,0.652
Burkina Faso,0.728
Burundi,0.699
Cambodia,0.714
Cameroon,0.711
Canada,0.688
Cape Verde,0.688
Central African Republic,0.782
Chad,0.681
Chile,0.777
China,0.55
Colombia,0.765
Comoros,0.711
Democratic Republic of the Congo,0.711
Republic of the Congo,0.711
Costa Rica,0.732
Ivory Coast,0.712
Croatia,0.654
Czech Republic,0.626
Denmark,0.808
Dominica,0.763
Dominican Republic,0.723
Ecuador,0.76
Egypt,0.689
El Salvador,0.746
Equatorial Guinea,0.688
Estonia,0.675
Ethiopia,0.652
Fiji,0.709
Finland,0.615
France,0.73
Gabon,0.784
Gambia,0.723
Georgia,0.725
Germany,0.667
Ghana,0.692
Greece,0.654
Grenada,0.763
Guatemala,0.779
Guinea-Bissau,0.71
Guinea,0.693
Guyana,0.707
Haiti,0.755
Honduras,0.743
Hong Kong,0.74
Hungary,0.651
Iceland,0.664
India,0.669
Indonesia,0.764
Iran,0.707
Ireland,0.581
Israel,0.677
Italy,0.609
Jamaica,0.686
Japan,0.547
Jordan,0.678
Kazakhstan,0.655
Kenya,0.699
Kyrgyzstan,0.68
Latvia,0.67
Lebanon,0.762
Lesotho,0.767
Lithuania,0.666
Luxembourg,0.65
Macau,0.58
North Macedonia,0.661
Madagascar,0.722
Malawi,0.736
Malaysia,0.733
Mali,0.75
Malta,0.664
Mauritania,0.686
Mauritius,0.661
Mexico,0.749
Moldova,0.691
Morocco,0.69
Mozambique,0.689
Namibia,0.847
Netherlands,0.65
New Zealand,0.651
Nicaragua,0.755
Niger,0.729
Nigeria,0.736
Norway,0.633
Pakistan,0.698
Panama,0.766
Papua New Guinea,0.738
Paraguay,0.766
Peru,0.738
Philippines,0.717
Poland,0.657
Portugal,0.667
Puerto Rico,0.753
Romania,0.651
Russia,0.699
Rwanda,0.714
São Tomé and Príncipe,0.711
Saudi Arabia,0.737
Senegal,0.697
Seychelles,0.76
Sierra Leone,0.687
Singapore,0.689
Slovakia,0.629
Slovenia,0.626
South Africa,0.763
South Korea,0.579
Spain,0.57
Sri Lanka,0.665
Saint Kitts and Nevis,0.763
Saint Lucia,0.763
Saint Vincent and the Grenadines,0.741
Swaziland,0.78
Sweden,0.742
Switzerland,0.803
Syria,0.704
Taiwan,0.655
Tajikistan,0.664
Tanzania,0.676
Thailand,0.71
Togo,0.711
Trinidad and Tobago,0.689
Tunisia,0.693
Turkey,0.718
Uganda,0.723
United Kingdom,0.697
Ukraine,0.667
Uruguay,0.708
United States,0.801
Venezuela,0.712
Vietnam,0.682
Yemen,0.613
Zambia,0.766
Zimbabwe,0.845
```

(*personal opinion*: a table works much better than a map, because it's sortable, and  countries aren't hidden or exaggerated by their size.)